# Generate XML feeds or auto export files in SAP?

Tags: excel, xml, sap-erp, saprfc

Is there any way to generate automatically the result of an SAP transaction? Let's say I want to see the production orders for one MRP controller (I have the COOIS transaction for this). Is there any way to generate an XML feed with the result of that transaction and refresh it let's say.. every 10 minutes?
Or to auto-export an .xls file with the result somewhere... ? I know I have the jobs and the spools but I have to manually download the result from the SAP GUI.
I don't have access to ABAP so I would like to know if there are other methods to get data from SAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "a transaction" might be anything from a simple report to a complex interactive application that does not even have a simple "result", I doubt that there's a way to provide any generic tool for this. You might try the following:

- Schedule a job and have the result sent to some mailbox instead of printing it. Then use the programming language of your choice to grab and process the mail.
- Check whether there are BAPIs available (BAPI_PRODORD_* or something like that - I'm not a CO expert, so I wouldn't know which one to use). You can call these BAPIs from an external program without having to write ABAP yourself - however, you'll most likely need the help of someone who knows ABAP in order to get the interface documentation and understand the concepts.